# waveform diagrams in RedHawk 2.0 after launch

Tags: redhawksdr

RedHawk 2.0 has a nicely improved waveform diagram editor and display.  I have a waveform with 14 components and I can carefully lay them out to see all components and paths.  But when the waveform is launched RedHawk brings up a new diagram of the waveform and all 14 components are on top of each other in the upper left of the window, which is of little use.  I can rearrange the diagram but would have to do this every time it launches.  Is there a way to get them to be displayed as they were saved when the diagram was edited?

And if I try to print it, I just get a blank page.

Comment: This problem seems to vary from installation to installation.  I have another 2.0 installation that works as expected.

Comment: But it also prints only blank pages.

Comment: Ah, it just has problems with waveforms that have data flowing both directions.  That is A->B->C but also C->B->A.  It does not use the original diagram but tries to lay one out using the connection paths but cannot handle the cases were they cross over each other to get from an out on the right side to the in on the left side of a component to the left.

Comment: Almost all of the waveforms I am interested in have data flowing both directions through a chain of components.

Comment: "Export Diagram" to any graphic file type also results in a blank image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedHawk v2.0 displays a waveform diagram when the waveform launche, which it colors to show status.  It does not use the diagram layout edited when the waveform is defined, but rather tries to layout the diagram using the components and connection lines.  It does a fairly nice job as long as the connections are all one direction with arrows pointing left to right, but if there are components that also have right to left connections, it gets confused and puts all the components on top of one another in the upper-left corner.  So waveforms that have connections in both directions (eg, bidirectional traffic, such as for a transceiver) become unreadable.

Comment: Using "Apply Horizontal Tree Layout" from the menu also shows same results as at runtime.